# Grails controller actions throws 404 error

Tags: grails, http-status-code-404

I'm using Intellij Idea IDE to build Grails 3 web apps, whenever I do Rebuild project the actions in controllers starts throwing 404 errors, I checked the URL Mapping and found no issues with it, in order to make these actions work again I need to open controllers and do some changes and then click on "Make", can anyone suggest a solution for this?

Comment: You shouldn't have to perform a rebuild yourself, Grails should automatically detaect changes to any controllers and perform a live-reload itself. Do you see `File /my-grails-app/grails-app/controllers/com/myapp/SomeController.groovy changed, recompiling...` in your output when saving a modified controller?

Comment: Yes I see that, but the changes I made to the code is not being reflected in the app, so I thought rebuilding is the way.

Comment: how are you starting your app?